# How to use razor pages and controllers in the same .net core 3 app?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here's the code for configuration in startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddControllers();
  services.AddRazorPages();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

I would like to have all of the controllers mapped under '/api' and everything else maps to razor pages.  I've done a ton of searching the web, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Here it is answered and working fine.
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298701/razor-pages-and-webapi-in-the-same-project)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no problem with your `startup.cs`.If you want to map all `/api` to your controller, then just decorate your api controller with attribute routing like:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Then create a `Pages` folder in your project where locates Razor Pages.
[image]

Comment: This is exactly the solution I ended up with :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this yet?

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e6557104-d06a-418c-a1a9-b8ce248f60b1.aspx

Looks like it can be done. You just won't call `services.AddRazorPages();`

Let me know what you see wrong with this or if it works.