# Adding Website to a webapi project in aspnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, razor-pages

I created a web api project , in aspnet core by following the wizard. [image]

Now my client wants me to create a few web pages too in the same project.

So if my apis are accessed by the URL abc.com/api/students.
Now a url like abc.com/students should open a page .

I wasn't able to find any links on the internet as to how should i go about turning a web api project into a web application so that I can make razor pages in it complete with its own routing etc.

Isn't this doable ?..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Razor pages and webapi in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298701/razor-pages-and-webapi-in-the-same-project)

Comment: Gusman I'll see and let ya know

Comment: Gusman yes it does speak about what i want to accomplish ..if you wish you can post this as an answer .